# Difference between zurechtkommen, auskommen, and klarkommen

Tags: translation, meaning, english-to-german, difference

Is there a difference between these three words? For example:

1. Ich komme mit meiner Schwester gut aus
2. Ich komme mit meiner Schwester gut zurecht
3. Ich komme mit meiner Schwester gut klar

Is there a difference in the meanings of these sentences?

For example, if a store employee asks me, "Are you getting along alright?" while I'm shopping, could he/she use any of the above terms, say, "Kommst du gut klar?"

Comment: The third one is very colloquial.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But in essence, all three can be translated as "get along"? For example, if a store employee asks me, "Are you getting along alright?" while I'm shopping, could he/she use any of the above terms, say, "Kommst du gut klar?"

Comment: good point! This is exactly what you should have asked in the main body, so we know what made you wonder!

Answer (score 5):

I will conduct more careful analysis over time. But I shall point to two important caveats:

### Auskommen

In the sense of *getting along*,  *auskommen* can only refer to people. It presupposes some mention of people:

> Kommen Sie miteinander aus? / Do you get along with each other?

If we use it with objects, the meaning will usually change profoundly:

> Kommen Sie mit dem Auto zurecht/klar?

refers to your ability of handling the car and your level of comfort in doing so.

> Kommen Sie mit dem Auto aus?

asks whether the car is enough for you. It might be directed to a company's boss, wanting to accommodate five people. This is due to a meaning of *auskommen* which I would translate as *make do*.

> Kommen Sie mit dem Geld aus? / Can you get through (the month, year...) with the money?

Therefore, the shop employee from your comment will **not** use:

> "Kommen Sie aus?".

I will conduct investigations into dialects and regional customs after the end of the exam period here. Unless some users come along to inform us of different usage.

### Klarkommen

This is far too colloquial to always be used in a professional context. It is safer for the employee to choose:

> Kommen Sie zurecht?